# Expected value and Integral

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value

I am trying to figure out when for a positive random variable $X_t$ it is ok to write
$$
E(\int_a^b X_tdt)=\int_a^b E(X_t)dt
$$

I know the theorems about infinite sums an that it is ok to pull $E$ into the sums if the random variables are positive but I am really confused somehow about this one. Only thing I can explain myselfe is that Riemann-sums are used.

Comment: Why do you need the RVs to be positive?

Comment: Do you know Lebesgue integral and measure theory ? Take a glance to Fubini's theorem. Luca, since the variable isn't integrable, you need at least positiveness

Comment: @ThéodorL. yes, how is it for use here? thank you for the reply.

Comment: @LucaCiti it does not need to be positive, it just happens to be positiv in my case (and because I know the theorems about infinite sums and expectation which I thought may help me out here).

Comment: @KingDingeling I see, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this depends on the dependence of $X_t$ on $t$.  For Fubini (or Tonelli), we need the map $(\omega,t) \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ to be measurable in the product sigma-algebra.

---

Any counterexample to Fubini could be adapted to this situation.  Here is a simple one.

Sierpinski showed (using to the continuum hypothesis) that there is a set $E \subseteq [0,1]\times[0,1]$ such that

for every $t \in [0,1]$, the set $\{\omega \in [0,1] : (\omega,t) \in E\}$ is countable, but

for every $\omega \in [0,1]$, the set $\{t \in [0,1] : (\omega,t) \in E\}$ is cocountable [i.e. the complement is countable.]

Taking our probability space to be $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, we define
$$
X_t(\omega) = \begin{cases}
1,\qquad & (\omega,t) \in E
\\
0,\qquad & (\omega,t) \notin E
\end{cases}
$$

Then, for each fixed $\omega$ we have $\int_0^1 X_t(\omega)\,dt = 1$ (the integrand is $1$ except on a countable set) and thus
$$
\mathbb E \int_0^1 X_t\;dt = 1 .
$$
On the other hand, for each fixed $t$ we have $\mathbb E[X_t] = 0$ (the random variable $X_t$ is zero almost surely) and thus
$$
\int_0^1\mathbb E(X_t)\;dt = 0 .
$$

Answer (score 0):

If we are working with $\sigma$-finite measure spaces (like ($\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda) )$ the best answer could be Fubini's theorem.

The Tonelli's theorem simply conclude exactly what you're looking for ($f$ measurable non-negative):
$$ \int_X \int_Y f(x,y) dy \ dx = \int_Y \int_X f(x,y) dx \ dy$$
(The expected value can be interpreted as an integral).